# Windows 7 virtual memory size

Tags: windows-7, windows, memory, virtual-memory

I have computer with 4GB RAM running windows 7 64 bit edition. I have set paging file size 8000MB( both initial size and maximum size) according [this](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Change-the-size-of-virtual-memory) document, but after restart I'm seeing only 4GB memory in task manager.

What else should I do, to increase my virtual memory size?

Comment: Whatever you're looking at in the task manager is probably just showing how much physical ram you have.

Comment: @martineau looks like really It was showing only physical memory, thanks. I'm pretty sure, that in windows xp graph in task manager is showing virtual memory size, not physical memory.

Comment: Too late, oh well. Happy computing!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had never though about this before, but as far as I can tell, Task Manager only reports on physical memory. I suggest that you just look at the root of the drive you put the virtual memory files (pagefile.sys) on, and make sure they total the 8000MB you set. If they are there, you are fine.

[image]

You might find this document about memory, virtual memory and page files useful:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2267427

Comment: Yes, the lower graph is showing physical memory, i.e. RAM. Both the line graph and the bar show the same thing. The part of the graph above the line corresponds to the "available" physical memory. 

You can actually infer your pagefile size from this display. You have 3070 MB physical memory, and your commit limit is 6139 MB (that's the second number where it says "Commit (MB)"). Since  commit limit is the current pagefile size + RAM (essentially), your current pagefile size must be 3069 MB. 3438 MB is the commit charge - the amount of the commit limit you are currently using.